# ConnectionClosedException while using Elastic RestHighLevelClient bulk request

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the following code for RestHighLevelClient in Elastic Search.

```js
val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(conf.value.getString("elkUserName"), conf.value.getString("elkPassword")))
val builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(conf.value.getString("elkIp"), Integer.valueOf(conf.value.getString("elkPort"))))
    .setRequestConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
        //set timeout
        override def customizeRequestConfig(requestConfigBuilder: RequestConfig.Builder): RequestConfig.Builder = requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Integer.valueOf(conf.value.getString("elkWriteTimeOut"))).setSocketTimeout(Integer.valueOf(conf.value.getString("elkWriteTimeOut")))
    }).setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
        override def customizeHttpClient(httpClientBuilder: HttpAsyncClientBuilder): HttpAsyncClientBuilder = {
            httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        }
    })
client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder)
val requestBuilder = RequestOptions.DEFAULT.toBuilder
requestBuilder.setHttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory(
    new HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory(1024 * 1024 * 1024))


var request = new BulkRequest()
request.setRefreshPolicy("wait_for")
var sizeOfRequest = 1 L
newListOfMap.foreach {
    vals =>
        val newMap = vals.asJava
    request.add(new IndexRequest(indexName).source(newMap))

}
client.bulk(request, requestBuilder.build)
```

But I am getting the following Exception

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: method <init>()V not found
  at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
unexpectedly at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:778)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:218)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:492)
  at Utils.ELKUtil$.postDataToELK(ELKUtil.scala:59)
```

NOTE: The above code is working for smaller size of request but getting above error while posting bigger size of request. Please suggest.

Comment: 1 point to notice is that Elastic cluster is running on Kubernetes

Answer (score 2):

If your project is using both `httpcore` and `httpcore-nio` dependencies, ensure that both of their versions are either simultaneously <= `4.4.10` or > `4.4.10`.

The suggestion by Harshit is partially what caused this issue in my case. On closer inspection of the logs, it is evident that `HttpAsyncRequestExecutor` is calling a default constructor called `ConnectionClosedException`, however, this default constructor does not exist in the destination

The `HttpAsyncRequestExecutor` is a class of `httpcore-nio` package. `ConnectionClosedException` is a class of the `httpcore` package. This issue starts occurring after **v4.4.10**, beyond which point the `ConnectionClosedException` class has a default constructor included which `HttpAsyncRequestExecutor` calls. For versions <= 4.4.10, the default constructor is not present, however, it is called with a parameter in `HttpAsyncRequestExecutor`. Thus the versions for both libraries should be either above or below **v4.4.10** when being used together.

Comment: how did you change the version of httpcore ?

Comment: @user2196474 Change the dependency versions in your pom.xml. If these are transitive dependencies in your project, you can override their versions by explicitly including them in you pom.xml (with the appropriate versions)

Comment: Thanks for your help. After changing jar version not getting this issue, but getting connection closed error

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue and the fix we that the service has `httpcore-4.4.3` where as the elastic client requires `httpcore-4.4.12`. So we updated all HTTP dependencies to map the version needed for `elastic-rest-high-level-client`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.5.2